# Problema com loop for em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loop, for

Quero que o *loop* abaixo for mostre todos os números pares que sejam menores ou iguais a ele, mas só consigo fazer com que ele mostre o último número. Se eu digito 40 e ele retorna só 2.

```
<div class="calculo">
    <input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="Informe o primeiro número: ">
    <button onclick = "pares()">Numeros Pares</button>
    <div id="resp"></div>

    <script>
        function pares(){
            var result = "";
            var num1 = parseInt (document.getElementById ("num1").value);
            for (num1 / 2 == 0; num1 > 0; num1 = num1 - 2) {
                document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = num1;
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira expressão do `for` está gerando um valor booleano, portanto não serve como inicializador. A inicialização deve considerar se o número digitado é par ou não, sendo ímpar deve diminuir 1 da variável para torná-la par e facilitar as contas.

Outro problema é que está substituindo o valor na `div`, então só o último permanece, tem que ir adicionando cada resultado.

```js
function pares() {
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value)
    for (num1 -= num1 % 2; num1 > 0; num1 -= 2) document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML += num1 + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="Informe o primeiro número: ">
<button onclick = "pares()">Numeros Pares</button>
<div id="resp"></div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Even.js).